# mysql module not found in Docker

Tags: docker, npm, module, mysql-connector

Working through some noobie issues with Docker... I'm trying to bring up a Node.js program as a container in Docker. The program is trying to connect to an existing MySql database that's already running in another container. The container name is "mysql", and the program name is "app".

The MySql that's currently running in Docker works fine, phpMyAdmin is running with it, everything works. It shows up correctly in the Docker Desktop as "mysql", and I can query it, connect to it from the bash shell, all good.

However - the app will not run, apparently because it can't find mysql. I thought NPM was supposed to automagically manage my dependencies?

This is the app code

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var dt = require('./mytestmodule');
```

This is the Dockerfile

```
FROM node
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

And this is the output from Docker

```
docker run --name mysecond --link mysql:db -p 8080:80 mysecond
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
Require stack:
- /usr/src/app.js
(... other stuff ...)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [ '/usr/src/app.js' ]
}
```

It looks like it's not finding the mysql module, yes?

I did install mysql using NPM, like I said it's working fine, in a Docker container, with phpMyAdmin running in another container. In that configuration, I link to the database as follows when starting phpMyAdmin:

```
docker run --name mysql -d -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=TRUE --expose 3306 --mount type=bind,source=/e/databases,target=/var/lib/mysql mysql

docker run --name myadmin -d -e PMA_ARBITRARY=1 --link mysql:db -p 8081:80 phpmyadmin
```

And this lets me access phpMyAdmin on port 8081.

My expectation was that this should work identically with my app.js, so I did it this way:

```
docker run --name app --link mysql:db -p 8080:80 app
```

And I expected the app to come up on localhost:8080, but it never gets that far.

What is happening, why is mysql not being found?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Dockerfile` exposes port 8080 but when you run the container you use `-p 8080:80` instead of `-p 8080:8080`.

Note that a good option to run multiple related containers is creating a `compose.yaml` that groups them as explained [in this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/).